# I want to display JSON data keys in html dropdown (not values)

Tags: javascript, html, json

https://api.myjson.com/bins/7xq2x this is my JSON data I want to display the keys in dropdown. My JSON data will be dynamic so I want code for dynamic JSON data to take only the keys

```
function renderBusinessUnitChart(){
   $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/7xq2x",
      success:function(result){

      }
  });

}
$(document).ready(function(){
    renderBusinessUnitChart();
});
```

Keys: `name`, `abbreviation` - this should display in dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For displaying keys:

```js
function renderBusinessUnitChart(){
  var ddown = document.querySelector('#dropdown')  // I don't know what kind of dropdown do you have, so we will use regular select

   $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/7xq2x",
      success:function(result){
        const itemKeys = Object.keys(result[0])    // getting keys from first item of result array
      
        var options = itemKeys.map(key => {        // looping the keys
          const option = new Option(
              key,
              key
            )                                      // creating a one option item for dropdown
          
          ddown.appendChild(option)                // adding option to dropdown
          
          return option                            // returning option and adding it to array
        })
        console.log (options)                      // aray of options you will need it for some reason
      }
  });

}
$(document).ready(function(){
    renderBusinessUnitChart();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown"></select>
```

For displaying keys where objects can contain different keys:

```js
function renderBusinessUnitChart(){

  // I don't know what kind of dropdown do you have, so we will use regular select
  var ddown = document.querySelector('#dropdown') 

   $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/7xq2x",
      success:function(result) {
        result = [ // for testng purposes only, to check that result may contain objects with different keys
          {"name":"Alberta","abbreviation":"AB"},
          {"name2":"British Columbia","abbreviation2":"BC"}
        ]
       
        const options = result     // getting array of unique keys from every item in result
          .reduce((ac, item) => [...ac, ...Object.keys(item).filter(key => !~ac.indexOf(key))], []) 
          .map(key => {  // looping the keys

            // creating a one option item for dropdown          
            const option = new Option(key, key)                                      
          
            // adding option to dropdown
            ddown.appendChild(option)                
          
            // returning option and adding it to array
            return option                            
          })

        // aray of options you will need it for some reason
        console.log (options)                      
      }
  })

}

$(document).ready(function(){
    renderBusinessUnitChart()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown"></select>
```

For displaying values:

```js
function renderBusinessUnitChart(){
  var ddown = document.querySelector('#dropdown')  // I don't know what kind of dropdown do you have, so we will use regular select

   $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/7xq2x",
      success:function(result){
        var options = result.map(_ => {            // looping the result
          const option = new Option(
              _.name,
              _.abbreviation
            )                                      // creating a one option item for dropdown
          
          ddown.appendChild(option)                // adding option to dropdown
          
          return option                            // returning option and adding it to array
        })
        console.log (options)                      // aray of options you will need it for some reason
      }
  });

}
$(document).ready(function(){
    renderBusinessUnitChart();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown"></select>
```

Comment: OP says they want to display the _keys_ and not the _values_.

Comment: You are welcome ;) btw, I just updated answer so the code is ready if your result will contain different objects (not only 2 keys like `name`, `abbreviation`)

Comment: can you give me the old one @qiAlex

Comment: I want another dropdown where if i selected  one value in dropdown that value should not display in another dropdown (e.g if name is selected in 1st dropdown it should not display in 2nd dropdown its should show only abbreviation) @qiAlex

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.keys(inputObject)` method to get an array of `inputObject` keys.
So in your case:

```
// Need to make sure your result is an object instead of array;
var resultObj = Array.isArray(result) ? result[0] : result;
function populateOptions(resultObj){
    return Object.keys(resultObj).map(key => {
        return `<option value="${key}">${key}</option>`
    }).join("");
}
var selectHtml = `<select>${populateOptions(resultObj)}</select>`
```

**See more:**

- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [Template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (it's the ``` (``) ``` syntax)
- [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)